# How to restrict to certain colours a gsheet cell range can take?

Tags: google-sheets

in my gsheet in a range, users are only allowed to use certain predefined colours as bg colour. The issue is that I have a script function that counts the number of cells with a certain colour. Users might accidentally choose the wrong colour tone which will lead to uncounted cells. So the question is how can I restrict colours of cells so that users can't go for the wrong colour?

Comment: I dont think that is possible but you could use a script to determine which colour the user would be trying to insert and then set it to what it is suppossed to be. For example a user sets the background colour to light green, the script detects it and sets it to standard green. Would you be open to a solution using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) or do you exclusively want a Google Sheets formula solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you write code which gets triggered by the onEdit() event.  You would use a function similar to the one I shared below to get the current cell color and if it is not within a array of colors that you allow, correct the color and throw a error/alert.

```js
function GetCellColorCode(input) 
{ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var cell = ss.getRange(input); 
  var result = cell.getBackground(); 
  return result 
}
```